# I need to build an executable, where do I begin

Tags: sql, pdf, executable, dropbox

I've been tasked to build a program which provides a UI that creates, imports, edits and exports database files and generates PDF (or PDF convertible) reports based on the database information. I want to store and backup database files and folders using Dropbox. Database information will consist of text and images.

My problem is my only programming experience is in firmware design for microcontrollers or similar hardware at which I am proficient. I have minimal experience in software design though I have some basic fundamentals down from my college years. I've spent a lot of time working in C language and I have previous experience using java. I have no experience creating executables or working with database files or producing nice PDF reports from buffered information.

My primary question is where do I begin? What advice would you give on where to start? Is it realistic that someone with my experience could learn how to build this sort of program in a 4-6 month period? What tools would you use? Is there anything particularly difficult about what I'm trying to do? Do you know of any useful tutorials or learning programs that would help me get my foot in the door?

Thank you,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to tackle this problem. We all come from different backgrounds and experiences. Here is how I would approach the problem. However, there may be limitations based on your budget and licensing options!

I would utilize QT and its many supplemental libraries as the core framework for the system.

- [Use QML to create front end](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlfirststeps.html)
- Pass data between front end and controller c++ file. '[Expose c++ to qml]'[2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)
- Use [QT database API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-connecting.html) to I/O with whatever you are targetting.
- [Use QPdf writer to write the PDF file.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfwriter.html)
- For image processing use something like [openCV](https://opencv.org/)

This solution would utilize mostly c++ and QML to tackle the project.